# Android GridView tutorial example does not show a grid

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

Hello I'm learning how to use a GridView in android
i found this simple example
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
I did everything that was written, step by step, there are no errors,
my aplication run ok, but its still empty screen with name of the aplications on the top, but there are no the gridView.
What is going on?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.slawek.hellogridview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

HelloGridView.java

```
package com.example.slawek.hellogridview;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ImageAdapter;

public class HelloGridView extends AppCompatActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

ImageAdapter.java

package com;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.slawek.hellogridview.R;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.slawek.hellogridview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: paste your code my friend

Comment: Do you have your drawables?

Comment: looks like you have some problems in your code. Once you fix them - it will work (yes, I know it's obvious, but there is nothing else to tell you as for the question the way you have asked it). You may ask *Where is the problem in my code?*, and I'll answer that I can tell you only after you **show your code**.

Comment: Please post your code.. So than anyone can solve your problem..

Comment: yes i have drawables

Comment: Still we'll be able to solve your problem faster and efficiently if you can share your code.\

Comment: here you are the code

Comment: where do you set your intent filter? HelloGrid or MainActivity?

Comment: At what point do you start the `HelloGridView` Activity?

Comment: @SławekLis check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to set your intent filter to HelloGridView Like this, and remove it from MainActivity

```
  <activity android:name=".HelloGridView ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity ">

        </activity>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem being discussed; the solution isn't to make his `HelloGridView` the main/launcher activity but that's just my two cents.

Comment: I did, the `MainActivity` is the main/launcher activity. He just doesn't seem to be starting his other activity which will show the gridview, namely the `HelloGridView` activity. But it is missing the entry for that activity as well.

Comment: OK but my question is, why this information is not in tutorial, I think I must be a fairy..

Answer (score 0):

```
     Your AndroidManifest.xml file in replace .MainActivity
       <activity
        android:name=".HelloGridView">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```